# Linking libcurl statically on linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, libcurl

I'm building an app which uses `http` service of curl library. I want to `statically` link the `libcurl` to my program.

Here is my `CMakeList.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(myprog)

# Set the build type to Release
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

# Add your source files
set(SOURCES 
    main.cpp
)

# Create the executable
add_executable(myprog ${SOURCES})


# Find libcurl
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

# Link the libcurl library statically
set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
set(CURL_STATICLIB TRUE)

target_link_libraries(myprog PRIVATE
    CURL::libcurl
    ${CURL_LIBRARIES}
    ${CURL_STATIC_LIBRARIES}
)
   
# Set linker flags to disable symbol generation
set_target_properties(myprog PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE "-s")
```

After building, the `ldd` shows that it still uses `libcurl.so` file

```
ubuntu@ubuntu: ldd myprog
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe5de9000)
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f67bfcc4000)
```

The `libcurl.a` is present on my machine at the following path:-

```
ubuntu@ubuntu: find /usr/lib -name libcurl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a
```

How can i instruct `cmake` to use the `static` version ?

Comment: `CURL::libcurl ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_STATIC_LIBRARIES}` - why not, if you specify all available kinds of libraries? BTW two `set` under `# Link the libcurl library statically` do not have any affect, because they are used for configuring sub-projects, but you don't do it.

Comment: Doesn't look like `find_package` for curl has any options to link statically https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18378. You might have to manually specify the path to the static library

Comment: I have added path/to/libcurl.a in my cmake i.e. target_link_libraries(clienthttp PRIVATE "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a")
But it doesn't solve the problem because then the linker doesn't find symbols of openssl, zlib etc etc.

Comment: "But it doesn't solve the problem because then the linker doesn't find symbols of openssl, zlib etc etc." - So you need to link with these libraries manually. This is a downside of static linking: unlike to dynamic libraries, static ones doesn't contain information about libraries they depends on.